# Regular expression to match a limited number of characters including an unlimited number of white spaces?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for US addresses (rough search) by matching a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to 2-5 digits or some PO Box stuff, followed by 10-100 characters, followed by a state and a zip.

I'm trying to limit the middle match to 10 to 100 of any character including new lines, while specifically allowing an unlimited number of white space characters within (all other characters are limited to a total of 100). For example, the following string would match:

```
"12345 First St. [hundreds of white space characters]
 Some Town, [hundreds of white space characters]
 CA 92107"
```

This regular expression matches my pattern except for the unlimited spaces.

```
$regex = '/(.|\n|\r\n){10,100}/';
```

I've tried this to match unlimited white space with this pattern, but it does not work:

```
$regex = '/(.|\s+|\n|\r\n){10,100}/';
```

For context, the complete regular expression I'm using to look for addresses is below:

```
$regex = "/\b(\d{2,5}|po|p\.o\.|post office)(.|\n|\r\n){10,100}(AK|Alaska|AL|Alabama|AR|Arkansas|AZ|Arizona|CA|California|CO|Colorado|CT|Connecticut|DC|Washington\sDC|Washington\D\.C\.|DE|Delaware|FL|Florida|GA|Georgia|GU|Guam|HI|Hawaii|IA|Iowa|ID|Idaho|IL|Illinois|IN|Indiana|KS|Kansas|KY|Kentucky|LA|Louisiana|MA|Massachusetts|MD|Maryland|ME|Maine|MI|Michigan|MN|Minnesota|MO|Missouri|MS|Mississippi|MT|Montana|NC|North\sCarolina|ND|North\sDakota|NE|New\sEngland|NH|New\sHampshire|NJ|New\sJersey|NM|New\sMexico|NV|Nevada|NY|New\sYork|OH|Ohio|OK|Oklahoma|OR|Oregon|PA|Pennsylvania|RI|Rhode\sIsland|SC|South\sCarolina|SD|South\sDakota|TN|Tennessee|TX|Texas|UT|Utah|VA|Virginia|VI|Virgin\sIslands|VT|Vermont|WA|Washington|WI|Wisconsin|WV|West\sVirginia|WY|Wyoming)(\s|\n|\r\n|\&nbsp\;){1,3}\d{5}/i"
```

Comment: How do you mean unlimited whitespace? Are whitespaces not counted in the 100 character limit?

Comment: I added a sample string that should match my requested regex.

Comment: I suspect you won't be able to do this with just a regex. What language is running the regex and can you include code?

Comment: Why don't you strip out the spaces before running the string through the regexp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following for your middle match:

```
\s*(?:\S\s*){10,100}
```

Regular expression:

```
\s*            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 (?:           group, but do not capture (between 10 and 100 times)
  \S           non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
  \s*          whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 ){10,100}     end of grouping
```

So you could start off your expression something like..

```
(\d{2,5}|post office|p[\. ]?o\.?)(\s*(?:\S\s*){10,100})
```

Live [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/hN5rR9) with your data.

Comment: Awesome and complete explanation of your solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an anchored lookahead to assert the overall number of non-blanks:

```
^(?=(\s*\S){10,100)\s*$)\d{1,5}.*[A-Z]{2}\s+\d{5}$
```

The lookahead asserts that there are 10-100 non-whitespace chars. I've also roughed out a basic regular expression for the actual address based on your comments.

Comment: The OP requires at least 10 _non-whitespace characters_, which might be interleaved with any number of whitespace characters

Comment: I'm commenting at your last remark "it seems a bit strange to require at least 10 spaces throughout the input"

Comment: @justhalf whoops! Got the reqs back to front. Fixed my regex accordingly. Thanks.